# gcc - Makefile: recipe for target 'all' failed after adding dependency rule

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I have a Makefile that fails every time I run it. I have been altering a Makefile that is compiling a bunch of files into a directory that needs to be made if it is not already. `all:` fails, and I honestly have no clue why it does.

Here is what my Makefile looks like:

```
CC=gcc
SRCDIR=src
INCDIR=include
BINDIR=../bin
CFLAGS = -flags
LIBS = -llibrary1 -llibrary2

all: 
    $(BINDIR) \
    $(BINDIR)/program1 \
    $(BINDIR)/program2 \
    $(BINDIR)/program3

$(BINDIR)/program1: $(SRCDIR)/program1.c | $(BINDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ $(LIBS)

$(BINDIR)/program2: $(SRCDIR)/program2.c | $(BINDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ $(LIBS)

$(BINDIR)/program3: $(SRCDIR)/program3.c | $(BINDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ $(LIBS)

$(BINDIR):
    mkdir -p $@

clean:
    rm -f $(BINDIR)/*
```

I know that the issue has to do with the `$(BINDIR)`, but I can't figure out what to do. The last question I asked on StackOverflow gave me some resources (such as GNU's documentation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types)). From my understanding, `$(BINDIR)` should be made first when I run make, and then the other rules should execute without any issues.

Here is the error I receive, which I know means that `$(BINDIR)` is not being created before the rest of the rules execute.

```
user@user-Notebook:~/project/folder$ make
../bin \
    ../bin/program1 \
    ../bin/program2 \
    ../bin/program3
make: ../bin: Command not found
Makefile:16: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 127
```

What am I missing?

Comment: From [An Introduction to Makefiles](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Introduction): _**Please note:** you need to put a tab character at the beginning of every command line! This is an obscurity that catches the unwary._ I'm not sure whether they are lost by copy/paste or really missing in your sample makefile.

Comment: Though, `make: ../bin: Command not found` wouldn't make sense if tabs were missing. So, may be, it's the opposite way: You want `all: $(BINDIR)` as dependency but inserted tabs. Hence, it tries to execute `$(BINDIR)` when you `make all`. May be, have a look at the linked doc. and try to understand how it works (not everything but the bit - enough to make your makefile running).

Comment: Just add a backslash after `all:`. The tab distinction doesn't matter for escaped lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posting this as an answer as it wouldn't fit in a comment:

Would make more sense that ***$(BINDIR)***(***/program***), to be **dependent(s)** for the ***all*** target, not commands:

```
all: $(BINDIR) $(BINDIR)/program1 $(BINDIR)/program2 $(BINDIR)/program3
```

Check [[GNU]: An Introduction to Makefiles](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_2.html#SEC4) for more details.

Things could be taken even further (e.g. writing an *pattern rule* that would handle all the files), in order to make the *Makefile* more compact.

***@EDIT0***:

Per @o11c's comment, I removed some part of the answer that was incorrect

Comment: No, the `|` is correct, to avoid caring about the directory timestamp.

Comment: @o11c: thank you for your input. I corrected the answer.

Comment: Thank you!! That was what I was missing!

Comment: @Kate: glad to be helpful! (on behalf of everyone involved)

Answer (score 0):

As currently written your 'all' rule has no dependencies and a non empty recipe. Thus make is trying to execute your dependency list as shell instructions. This is why you see the command not found error, it is from the shell. Remove the newline after `all:` and it should work.